# What is the meaning of "They are more often a lump than a sum"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idioms, phrase-meaning

So I was watching a TV show called Hannibal. I was on the last episode of season three, called "The Wrath of the Lamb".

So Will Graham (a character from the show) was having a talk with psychiatrist Bedelia Du Maurier (another character).

Their disscussion:

> **Bedelia Du Maurier:** "We assign a moment to decision. What you propose is so thoughtless, I find difficult to imagine that moment exists."
>
> **Will Graham:** "Decisions are made of kneaded feelings. They are more often a lump than a sum."

I can't really understand Will Graham's statement. I understand the part "Decisions are made of kneaded feelings" but I can't understand the other part. What is meant by "lump than a sum"?

Is it some kind of idiom? I have searched, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: It's a play on words for the idiom "lump sum".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an unusual turn of phrase, and it would be helpful to have more context.

From [Adequote](http://adequote.com/thomas-harris-hannibal-2/#.V4Czu7grLRY):

> We assign a moment to decision, to dignify the process as a timely
> result of rational and conscious thought. But decisions are made of
> kneaded feelings; they are more often a lump than a sum.
>
> - Thomas Harris, *Hannibal*

The author is saying that we tend to regard (and describe) decisions as being made at a definite time and after carefully weighing all the factors involved, but that in fact the process involved is neither so logical (being largely emotion-driven) nor so linear, nor so easy to analyse.

Comment: Nice work tracking down the quote - though I'm guessing it's from the book rather than the series. In any case it gives valuable confirmation of the quite unusual wording. It's likely that the author is also making a wordplay of the expression "[lump sum](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lump-sum?s=t)" - though I'm not sure we can draw any additional understanding from this. It's more likely that the language is meant to appear more meaningful than it really is, as you'd expect from a pretentiously intellectual character.

Answer (score 0):

A difference between adding and mixing, that's why "kneaded" is used.

If you were to deposit three separate payments into a bank account, adding those three payments would give you a sum total. From that total, you could extract any one of those three payments at its exact amount.

If you were to throw ingredients into a bowl and mix them together, you couldn't extract any one of those ingredients at its exact amount. When kneaded, they'd be more like a lump of dough.

That's why Will has such a problem in 2x13. He can't cut out the part that wants to run away with Hannibal. He's torn between two friends.